# Attempting to build a custom terraform provider, encountering errors with the helpers/schema module

Tags: go, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'll start off by saying I'm completely new to Go and having a lot of trouble figuring out its environment.

I'm attempting to make a custom terraform provider by following the instructions in [this guide](https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/writing-custom-terraform-providers).

When attemping to run `go mod tidy` after setting up the project files, it is unable to pull in the required modules. This is the error I get:

```
github.com/hashicorp/terraform/terraform: module github.com/hashicorp/terraform@latest found (v.1.3.2), but does not contain package github.com/hashicorp/terraform/terraform
```

I get this same error for pretty much all the requirements.

Can someone ELI5 how I'm supposed to setup my Go environment so that I can write a custom tf provider? Thanks.

Comment: "I'm completely new to Go". I would recommend spending a decent amount of time working on that before attempting provider development.

Comment: Why did you tag this with `terraform-provider-aws` if it is not a question about using the Terraform AWS provider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The guide you are following is terribly outdated (from 2014). Since it was written, they reorganized plugin SDK several times, slightly newer is I believe `terraform-plugin-sdk` which I don't recommend learning at all. **Latest and recommended SDK** is called [`terraform-plugin-framework`](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-framework).

Up to date documentation with examples is here: [Implement a Provider with the Terraform Plugin Framework](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/providers-plugin-framework-provider?in=terraform/providers-plugin-framework). It will walk you trough environment setup and bootstrapping a new custom provider.